# Apex class will NOT save locally

Tags: ide, eclipse, subversion, version-control

I am fairly new to SF development, and I have a SF sandbox and am using Eclipse along with Subclipse and SVN to manage it.

I created a new test class under classes, and added it to SVN.  It shows up in the Package Explorer with the little SVN "plus" sign.  But when I try to commit it, it says that it is not on the file system, and in fact, when I look there, it is not.   The class has been saved to the server, and it runs fine both there and in the Eclipse test runner.

What am I missing here?  None of the "Team" or "Force" options seem to apply.

Thanks,

Mitch

Comment: You will need the Force.com IDE to use Eclipse to manage Salesforce.com metadata. Can you confirm that you have installed the Force.com IDE plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: Are you sure that either the force.com  plugin or the subversion repository are not placing the files in a different location than you're looking at ?

Comment: Sorry... yes, I definitely have the Force.com IDE installed, as well as Subclipse.  I have been using this for a bit, and was able to make changes and commit them before.  This is a new file that I created today to merge in some contractor's code.

Comment: Samuel,... you hit the nail on the head... I don't know how I got there, but I must have had an old SVN checkout laying around.  thanks!